# Python cannot import function from sibling module through non-relative path

Tags: python, import

In the project I'm working on there is a file structure like the one that I recreated here:

```
tree Example/
Example/
├── A
│   ├── functions.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── B
│   ├── functions.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

I'm trying to import in `B` a function defined in `A` and to avoid problems with the paths I used the full path instead of the relative one, as read on Stack Overflow.

Here is the code of `B`:

```
from Example.A.functions import a_function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a_function()
```

No matter where I run the `B/functions.py` from, I always get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Example'
```

How is that the module is not found even though:

1. Someone defined it since under `Example` there's an `__init__.py`.
2. This code has been running in production with this structure for years.

I read I could try to fix this with some modifications of the `sys.path` but I was wondering if this is the only way. How is this code running without someone having inserted the `sys.path.append(...)` then?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first quesry, you can set `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/Example`. Then in the `B/functions.py`, you can modify the import statement as

```
# from Example.A.functions import a_function <--- not this
from A.functions import a_function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a_function()
```

As we can read below, adding it to the PYTHONPATH should do the trick as well (which is a better approach than adding it to `sys.path` inside the code).

And regarding your second query, there are various ways to put your module to the path and you can analyse your prod env to figure this out.
[image]